# Android manifestmerger.enabled does not work for sharedUserId

Tags: android

In my Android library manifest file I have set sharedUserId property.
I have referenced to this lib project in my app1 and app2.
I have added  manifestmerger.enabled=true to project.properties files of both apps.
However sharedUserId does not work (note: it works ok if I set thisproperty to app manifest file directly).
While looking app/bin/AndroidManifest I dont see this property - so looks like merge didn't happen.
I am using Eclipse ADT build22.3.0

Any idea what is the problem?
Basically what I want is to have ability to expose propery from my jar library.

Comment: sharedUserId is a property with such serious implications that it would be entirely reasonable for the android team to have decided that this should not be something a library can quietly merge in, but rather something that must be explicitly set in the Apps's own manifest file.  Does merging of other elements work?

Comment: Dont think this is the reason. I believe the merge just does not work. I have added my dummy meta-data to lib manifest - dont see it was merged to app manifest in bin directory.

Comment: For more general issues with the manifest merge, you may want to see the several other questions on that topic here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended to work.

From the [inline documentation of the ManifestMerger class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/a35f8af9eca38249b5c37391d7a7ae56c53251ad/manifmerger/src/com/android/manifmerger/ManifestMerger.java)

```
 - root manifest: attributes ignored, warn if defined.
```

The Android [Manifest documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) lists `android:sharedUserId` under the root element of the Manifest file, so it will be in the group of things which *cannot* be merged in from a library.

You may of course have additional issues preventing merging from working *in general* but even after those are corrected it *should not* work for sharedUserId (and other root level attributes) *in specific*.

Comment: Yes. Looks like you are correct. I have confirmed the activity is merged correctly.   The issue is with root  elements :(:(:(:(  Thanks a lot for the reply and usefull link though.